# Display work items which are waiting until backend service finishes

Tags: filenet-p8, ibm-content-navigator, filenet-process-engine

In my workflow I have iterative loop which check the table value until it matches a workflow value using DB Execute.

This stage arise after completing initial and step  After values matches it will proceed to next step.this has created by adding delay function.

However my client required to show the list work items which are pending withing content navigator. Is there a way to achieve this.

Comment: From what I understand you want users to be able to see certain items that are currently in the delay queue? I do not think it is possible to show this queue to normal users. I think it can be done by implementing it as a custom page and create a custom vw query.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add users (who want to track status) in F_Trackers system Workflow Group.